Plato about dynamic of knowledge
Where did Plato say something like "what's the point in going back to a book if every time it gives the same answer"? Did ancient Greeks say anything about the dynamic of knowledge?

Written words vs dynamic engagement with words was very much discussed by Plato.
Plato's dialogues present a tension between the written word and dialectic, emphasizing the dynamic, interactive nature of dialectic as a means of pursuing truth. This perspective resonates with the idea that true understanding often requires active engagement, questioning, and critical thinking, rather than passive acceptance of written texts.
In "Phaedrus," Socrates tells a story about the Egyptian god Theuth presenting the invention of writing to King Thamus. Thamus expresses concern that this invention will lead to forgetfulness and a reliance on written words rather than true knowledge through dialogue and questioning.
In "Phaedo," Socrates discusses the limitations of the written word compared to dialectic. He argues that written texts cannot defend themselves or clarify their meaning, unlike a living person engaged in dialectic. Socrates emphasizes the importance of questioning and critical examination over passive acceptance of written texts.
